# Can the latest openlayers render the animated marker using gif/apng/webp?

Tags: html5-canvas, openlayers, webp, openlayers-6, apng

According to this QA, by using "gifler" library, we can use animated gif to render on canvas-based openlayers.
[can openlayers 3 render the animated marker using gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277959/can-openlayers-3-render-the-animated-marker-using-gif)

But it cannot accept apng/webp, and also, "gifler" library is bit old, it is tough to use with the latest EcmaScript or TypeScript.

Are there any other way to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I couldn't find a way to make it work, so I started developing it myself.
Animated GIF, APNG, and Animated webp can be frame-split and even animated on a canvas context in the following.

https://github.com/code4history/Gyeonghwon